# import PySide results in a segmentation fault

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

I've been searching for quite a while and haven't found any questions addressing this specific scenario.

I used pip to successfully build and install PySide (and a bunch of other packages) in python3.4.4 using RedHat 6.6 and GCC 4.4.5. However, python seg faults when I import PySide:

```
> python3.4
Python 3.4.4 (default, Mar  1 2016, 15:30:00) 
[GCC 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import PySide
Segmentation fault
>
```

The same thing happens if I do "from PySide import QtCore".

Does anyone know of an issue in this regard?
Can anyone suggest a method of debugging this?

Note: python was built on this same node with the same compiler, and seems to otherwise work fine. It was installed with "make altinstall" because python2.7.11 and python3.5.1 are also installed (all with "make altinstall").

Thanks much for any help.

Comment: It probably linked against the wrong python libs. Try rebuilding everything from source, rather than using pip.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro, I will try that. However, I didn't just invoke pip from the bin directory. Trying to ensure pip used the correct version of python, I called pip via python3.4 like "python3.4 -m pip install PySide".

Comment: You can see what libs it linked against with: `ldd path/to/QtCore.so`.

Comment: Yep.  Problem fixed by rebuilding PySide without using pip, and then installing the wheel with pip using options `--no-index --find-links=<path_to_wheelhouse_dir>`.